Страницы на React JS с модулем react-helmet-async некорректно индексируются (Google, Yandex)
Я использую react-helmet-async для оптимизации SEO и динамических meta тегов. Дело в том, что Google некоторые страницы (скажем их где то 30%) индексирует с неправильным title и meta description. Они могут отображатся как по дефолту (например как title и meta description указана для главной стр), так и вовсе без meta - как в Яндекс. Яндекс вообще жалуется что 90% страниц без title и description либо повторяются.
Вопросы:

В файле public/index.html - надо ли указывать  и meta description, не смотря на то, что в компонентах использую  с meta тегами
Чтобы указать мета теги главной страницы, куда должен пихнуть  с мета данными, в App.js или созданный мною отдельную главную страницу типо ?
В каком компоненте должен обернуть элементы в , в index.js или App.js?
Не устарел ли способ c react-helmet-async, может поисковики уже поменяли свою политику в отношении к helmet?

